# getting todays date and setting it in countdown

Tags: javascript

I've got a function that counts down the time to a specific date/time.
This is the code for it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(2017,05, 23, 09, 30, 59));
function time_remaining(endtime){
    var t = endtime - new Date();
    var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
    var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
    var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
    return {'total':t, 'days':days, 'hours':hours, 'minutes':minutes, 'seconds':seconds};
}
function run_clock(id,endtime){
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);

    var days_span = clock.querySelector('.days');
    var hours_span = clock.querySelector('.hours');
    var minutes_span = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
    var seconds_span = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

    function update_clock(){
        var t = time_remaining(endtime);

        days_span.innerHTML = t.days;
        hours_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutes_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        seconds_span.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if(t.total<=0){ clearInterval(timeinterval); document.getElementById('deadline_Container').style.display = "none"; document.getElementById('deadline_Container2').style.display = "block"; }
    }
    update_clock();
    var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock,1000);
}
run_clock('clockdiv',deadline);
</script>
```

Now I'm trying to set the date by getting the current date and only have the time (hours, minutes, seconds) always set to the same.
So I'm getting the current date like this:

```
  <script>
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd = '0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm = '0'+mm
} 

today = yyyy + ',' + mm + ',' + dd;
document.write(today);
</script>
```

I've tried including `var today` in `var deadline` so

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(today, 09, 30, 59));
```

but I'm getting a NaN error. Anybody know how to do this right?

Comment: `var clock = document.getElementById(id);` - change it to `var clock = document.getElementById('id');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so close, a simple enough mistake

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(today, 09, 30, 59));
```

This line needs amending to the following and add a new line before hand.

```
var mmm = today.getMonth();
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy,mmm,dd, 09, 30, 59));
```

That will work straight away for you.

The date object you are sending through to the UTC is not handled as more info than what is required.

Just used your variables, so declare a new one with out the +1 so it handles the month correctly as 5.(June).

Comment: Thanks, almost works- only problem it sets the month as 06, but that outputs as July so it says 30 days left instead of 0 as Januray= 0 etc.

Comment: @MariaL amended and declared new variable with out the +1 to the month used in your 'mm'. Now will set month correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the doc for Date.UTC method :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/UTC

You cannot use a Date as the first parameter of the method as a number is expected ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.UTC(yyyy,mm,dd,09, 30, 59));
```

Reason why when "today" doesnt work for you: Because today is passed and string, it should be in Int, so that it accepts date format.